# Regex to differentiate between two types of strings

Tags: regex

I have a WordPress XML file I have to do a find and replace on to switch plain YouTube URLs to the YouTube embed code.  I can't just do a wildcard search because the XML file also has anchor links to YouTube videos that need to remain as they are.

So, I have to find strings like this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qO7xcLFBIPI&amp;list=PLz0RLQy-mngFQ1I67MJGmH-7kfltr4neI
```

and this:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qO7xcLFBIPI
```

And replace them with this:

```
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qO7xcLFBIPI?list=PLz0RLQy-mngFQ1I67MJGmH-7kfltr4neI" 
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But **NOT** match this:

```
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLz0RLQy-mngFQ1I67MJGmH-7kfltr4neI"
```

or this:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=czZLV0ofaMc&amp;list=PLz0RLQy-mngFQ1I67MJGmH-7kfltr4neI">
```

I'm thinking that any youtube link that isn't wrapped in quotes would do it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I think a regex search and replace in Coda will do it but I'm not equipped with the knowledge in this area.

Cheers.

Comment: what about naked www.youtu.be links?

Comment: There are no youtu.be links in the entire document. And all of them start with `http://www.youtube`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `(^|[^"])(http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/[^\s"]*)`, and use the second match group.

[See example here](https://regex101.com/r/aS8kK9/3)

Explanation:

1. `(^|[^"])` finds the beginning of the line or any character other than a double quote; this is necessary to make sure you're not inside a double quote, but the match is ignored.
2. `http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/`, of course, finds "http://www.youtube.com/".
3. `[^\s"]*` finds all the characters up to, but *not* including, the next space (`\s`) or double quote (`"`).
4. 2 and 3 are framed in parentheses, forming the second match group, which is what you are looking for.